# iOS Navigation 'Back' Button Not Showing Title of Previous View

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, interface-builder

In my app, I have a child-view that I use for multiple navigation controllers.  It just loads a web view from a URL that is passed from its parent controller.  The issue is that on one of the navigation controllers, it shows the parent title on the back button, but on the other, it shows just the back button.  I have set the title in code, and in interface builder.  Why would this be happening?

Comment: its depends on the title length. if its too long then its not display

Answer (score -2):

The text of the back button of your child view actually depends on the view you come from, so you need to set it for every parent view, in their properties.

In the storyboard, select each parent view that you have, and edit the 'Back' string. Alternatively, you can set it in code.

Comment: Did this, and it still just shows Back but only when coming from the one parent view.